# Is there a way to check if data migration tool finished smoothly

Tags: magento2, data-migration

My data migration was running yesterday and it was taking so long. In 7 hours it completed only about 50%, so I left my computer turned on and making my computer to never sleep.

I check 11 PM from TeamViewer and it was still running and had finished 70%. 
I came back to work this morning at 9 AM and only to find my windows computer had restarted. Most likely it had auto-updated.

Now, is there a way to check if Data Migration finished its job?

And is it normal to take this much of the time to migrate data? I do have a DB of 45GB.

Please suggest.

Comment: did you truncate / exclude useless data before migration? usually there are 80% of logs, stats, search, reports and other crap...

Comment: Yeah, I realized yesterday. I truncated those tables and migration was smooth.

Answer (score 0):

This is the reply I got from Magento support team.

If you open `magento2root/var/migration.log` file and can see the last string like this

> [INFO][mode: data][stage: data migration][step: PostProcessing Step]:
>   started

then the migration is finished.

Regarding taking huge amount of time, I had to clean up some unnecessary data.

Hope this helps someone.